# Further enhance performance of Parallel.ForEachAsync() method

Tags: .net, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have a process that's grabbing data from a number of different sources, using the data to process a statistic, and returning back that statistic. I've added caching of duplicate entries, and I've set the MaxDegreesOfParallelism to -1 to try and use as much of the server resources as I can.

Here's a super simplified version of what I'm doing.

```
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(listOfIds, async (id, token) =>
{
    var context = new MyDbContext();              // spin up a new context each time to avoid concurrency issues.
    var service = new MyService(context);         // create new instance of service to avoid concurrency issues.
    try
    {
        var result = await service.getStatistic(id);
        // do something with the result
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // add to error message tracking
    }
});
```

This is working, but it's not as performant as I would like. Inside the getStatistic, I'm ONLY reading from a database, or pulling from an API (which is cached when possible, and also why I can't move this all to a stored procedure that does the stat generation) and the actual runtime of the `getStatistic` method is ~3 seconds. But spread across 180,000 records it's still taking near 5-10 hours to complete.

Aside from setting 'MaxDegreesOfParallelism' to -1, what else can I do to simply "throw more resources" at it?

Comment: 1. Db calls are better when batched; instead of doing a point query, batch a few hundred ids and return them all at the same time. 2. Try doing the async work separately and with full concurrency, and then doing the statistics part as a Parallel operation.